# Formula: Syntax error

Tags: formula, validation-rule

```
IF( 
OR(  
Date__c  < (TODAY() - MOD(TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8),7)), 
Date__c  > (TODAY() + MOD(TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8),7))
), 
true,
false)
```

The previous formula raises a syntax error.

Comment: Hi @AshishSoni, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Which Synxtax error are you getting? I'm getting no syntax error with your code (changing the Date__c field for another Date field)

Comment: Also note that the `IF` is redundant here.

Comment: Yes, you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing these `()` brackets across your `OR` conditions. It's good to use those `()` brackets if you've multiple conditions. Refer below:

```
IF( 
    OR( 
        (Date__c < (TODAY() - MOD((TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8)),7))),
        (Date__c > (TODAY() + MOD((TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8)),7)))
    )
    ,true,false 
)
```

Above validation might solve your problem but it's good to use `AND` instead of `IF`. Here is example:

```
AND( 
    OR( 
        (Date__c < (TODAY() - MOD((TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8)),7))),
        (Date__c > (TODAY() + MOD((TODAY()- DATE(1900,1,8)),7)))
    )
)
```

Comment: @AshishSoni You can accept the answer so that it could be useful for others too

Comment: The AND/IF are both unnecessary.